# Is there an equivalent to FX Console in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, adobe, plugins

The free [FX Console plugin](https://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/fx_console_plugin/) for After Effects allows you to instantly apply effects and other things to the selected clip. Is there an equivalent for Adobe Premiere? It would be a real timesaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Excalibur is and is even more polished than FX console but not for free :

https://knightsoftheeditingtable.com/excalibur